# PHP CSV to array - keep reading fields when one is empty

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I got like this CSV:

```
1|bla.jpg|nature
2|       |earth
```

When I convert the CSV to array like this:

```
while (($line = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ';')) !== FALSE)
{
    $data[] = $line;
}
```

then I get follow array in `$data`:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "bla.jpg"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "nature"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(163) "2"
  }
}
```

But I need it like that:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "bla.jpg"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "nature"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
    [2]=>
    string(5) "earth"
  }
}
```

How can I keep parsing CSV when one field is empty?

Ignore it: I need to add some more text -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use file() to read it as an array, then explode each line with ";".

```
// For demo purpose
$str = "1;bla.jpg;nature
        2;;earth";
$arr = explode(PHP_EOL, $str);
// End
// $arr = file("file.csv");

Foreach($arr as &$line) $line = explode(";", $line);

Var_dump($arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/9FdVQ

Since it was unclear.

```
$arr = file("file.csv");

Foreach(array_splice($arr,0,10) as &$line) $line = explode(";", $line);

Var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: Ok but how do I get the CSV into $str? $str = fopen('bla.csv', "r"); isn't working this way

Comment: Read the comments. You should **not** read it to string. The string is just for demo purpose to make it run on 3v4l. Use the commented line  `$arr = file("file.csv");`

Comment: And fopen does not return a string. If you want to read to string you need to use file_get_contents

Comment: Now it works thanks :D I never seen such weird syntax, could you also show how to get only first 10 lines? Ofc I could just slice the $arr after it's parsed completely but how could I only get first 10 lines from begine with?

Comment: See update with array_splice. What is the strange syntax

Comment: Now that I think about it you may need to wrap `file("file.csv")` with array_splice instead since the foreach does not return anything.

Comment: Like foreach without {} and so on, never seen that. Real advanced stuff :D Thanks again

Comment: One line foreach works just like an if with only one line. You don't need the {}

Comment: You are right about slicing file("file.csv"). All that makes fgetcsv totally pointless

Answer (score 1):

Set correct delimeter

```
while (($line = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, '|')) !== FALSE)
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/952400)

Comment: smh | isn't the delimeter I just use it here to make the table understandable/readable otherwise the first row wouldn't be parsed correctly

Comment: Why do you think is the first line parsed correctly?.................... the fields are separated with ;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe don't use fgetcsv, but read the entire line and use `explode(';', $line)` to split the line on each comma (or any other suitable delimiter ; csv files usually use ; but can also use , or tab)

Answer (score 0):

For me this code works as expected,

you should try:

- read another CSV file
- check the encoding of CSV file is proper (I suppose it should be a `UTF-8` encoding)
- check, that delimiters in the file are the same like in the code

Look into php docs:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

> Note: If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading
>   files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the
>   auto_detect_line_endings run-time configuration option may help
>   resolve the problem.

Maybe this problem is related to operating system, which was used to create this CSV file?